# Excel list all values that match criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to list all the cells containing the text "Ta" in a list that extrapolates the values ​​of column C and row 6.

I can't formulate a function that does it, would you be able to help me out
thank you

[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDT5T.png)
[ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1bLr.png)

Comment: Your image has the column and row values cropped out, so what is col C/row 6? Also, what do you mean by "List", an array of cell references?

Comment: Could your provide detail information about your requirement? It's not very clearly.

Comment: You want a table of the `C` value and the day, for each "Ta" value, right? But how do you decide which "Ta" day is the start/end, and how many are there? I don't understand much Italian...

Comment: Yes, "Ta" value will always take up one day, and 
there may be many on different rows and columns... It's possible?

Comment: @Fede It's very difficult with only formulas. The data is in a bad format for excel. For example, if you could re-format to three columns like `Date|C-data|cell-value`, then it would be as simple as filtering a table column. I tried some VBA with `Range.Find()` for every column to get the "Ta" cells, then getting the C:6 values, but ran out of time.